# What is the secret on the skull stage of Fez?

Tags: fez

Like the owl stage, it's in the dark, rainy zone, and there's a secret on the level. What is the trick?
[image]

Comment: They're two different situations, as far as I can tell. I'll delete or merge if I find out otherwise.

Comment: @sean No, please don't: they are separate questions. Perhaps if you can expand on what you've tried so far, it'd be easier to tell them apart.

Comment: Ah my apologies.  SKULL vs. owl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By turning all of the mini-skulls (hold X) so all of them are facing away from you at the same time, so will the giant skull, revealing the back of it's head.